Pandas window-like function to rid off time-stamp overlapping
I have a dataframe that contains promo campaign duration and I need to rid off time-stamp overlapping.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import Timestamp

t1 = np.array([['Store A', 32,
        Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
       ['Store A', 32,
        Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
       ['Store A', 32,
        Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
       ['Store A', 32,
        Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2024-04-11 00:00:00')],
       ['Store A', 32,
        Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2024-04-11 00:00:00')],
       ['Store A', 32,
        Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2024-04-11 00:00:00')],
       ['Store A', 32,
        Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2024-04-11 00:00:00')],
       ['Store A', 35,
        Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
       ['Store A', 35,
        Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
       ['Store A', 35,
        Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
       ['Store A', 35,
        Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
       ['Store A', 35,
        Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2024-04-11 00:00:00')],
       ['Store A', 35,
        Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2024-04-11 00:00:00')],
       ['Store A', 35,
        Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2024-04-11 00:00:00')],
       ['Store B', 66,
        Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
       ['Store B', 66,
        Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
       ['Store B', 66,
        Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
       ['Store B', 66,
        Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
       ['Store B', 66,
        Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2024-04-11 00:00:00')],
       ['Store B', 66,
        Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2024-04-11 00:00:00')]], dtype=object)

df = pd.DataFrame(t1)
df.columns = ['store', 'id', 'start', 'end']
df


Input table screenshot
Desired result screenshot
Is there way to get something like this? Maybe there is a solution without window functions? I've looked through dozens of pages on this topic but couldn't find anything like this.
At first glance it seems simple, but I'm stuck. The documentation does not say that the shift function can be applied to a window.

Post clear input and output dataframes. Reproducible output dataframe. Your images are good, but confusing still

As is mentioned in the comments, your desired output is confusing. So, if I read the text you wrote right, what you want is getting rid of overlapping intervals. I suggest creating a function that does just that. Also, you sample data is full of duplicates, so you need to eliminate those as well:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import Timestamp

t1 = np.array([
    ['Store A', 32, Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 32, Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 32, Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 32, Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-04-11 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 32, Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-04-11 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 32, Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-04-11 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 32, Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-04-11 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 35, Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 35, Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 35, Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 35, Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 35, Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-04-11 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 35, Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-04-11 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 35, Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-04-11 00:00:00')],
    ['Store B', 66, Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
    ['Store B', 66, Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
    ['Store B', 66, Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
    ['Store B', 66, Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
    ['Store B', 66, Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-04-11 00:00:00')],
    ['Store B', 66, Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-04-11 00:00:00')]
], dtype=object)

df = pd.DataFrame(t1, columns=['store', 'id', 'start', 'end'])

df = df.drop_duplicates()
print(df)
df = df.sort_values(by=['store', 'id', 'start']).reset_index(drop=True)

def merge_intervals(group):
    merged = []
    for start, end in zip(group['start'], group['end']):
        if not merged or merged[-1][1] < start:
            merged.append([start, end])
        else:
            merged[-1][1] = max(merged[-1][1], end)
    return pd.DataFrame(merged, columns=['start', 'end'])

result = df.groupby(['store', 'id']).apply(lambda group: merge_intervals(group)).reset_index()
result = result.drop(columns='level_2').drop_duplicates()

print(result)

which returns your df:
      store  id      start        end
0   Store A  32 2024-02-15 2024-03-14
3   Store A  32 2024-03-14 2024-04-11
7   Store A  35 2024-02-15 2024-03-14
11  Store A  35 2024-03-14 2024-04-11
14  Store B  66 2024-02-15 2024-03-14
18  Store B  66 2024-03-14 2024-04-11


and your expected output:
     store  id      start        end
0  Store A  32 2024-02-15 2024-04-11
1  Store A  35 2024-02-15 2024-04-11
2  Store B  66 2024-02-15 2024-04-11


Since you data have many repetitions you may want to eliminate duplicates,
operate on the subset, and reindex back to your original shape.
Once you do this, you can perform a grouped-shift to see if the 'start'
of any row is equivalent to the 'end'  of the previous row and if it is,
subtract 1 day from the end.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import Timestamp, Timedelta

t1 = np.array([
    ['Store A', 32, Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 32, Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 32, Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 32, Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-04-11 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 32, Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-04-11 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 32, Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-04-11 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 32, Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-04-11 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 35, Timestamp('2024-03-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-04-14 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 35, Timestamp('2024-03-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-04-14 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 35, Timestamp('2024-03-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-04-14 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 35, Timestamp('2024-03-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-04-14 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 35, Timestamp('2024-04-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-05-11 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 35, Timestamp('2024-04-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-05-11 00:00:00')],
    ['Store A', 35, Timestamp('2024-04-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-05-11 00:00:00')],
    ['Store B', 66, Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
    ['Store B', 66, Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
    ['Store B', 66, Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
    ['Store B', 66, Timestamp('2024-02-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00')],
    ['Store B', 66, Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-04-11 00:00:00')],
    ['Store B', 66, Timestamp('2024-03-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2024-04-11 00:00:00')]
], dtype=object)

df = pd.DataFrame(t1, columns=['store', 'id', 'start', 'end'])

print(
    df
    .drop_duplicates(['store', 'start', 'end'])
    .assign(
        end=lambda d:
            d['end'].mask(
                d.groupby('store')['start'].shift(-1) == d['end'],
                d['end'] - Timedelta(days=1)
            )
    )
    .reindex(df.index, method='ffill')
)
#       store  id      start        end
# 0   Store A  32 2024-02-15 2024-03-13
# 1   Store A  32 2024-02-15 2024-03-13
# 2   Store A  32 2024-02-15 2024-03-13
# 3   Store A  32 2024-03-14 2024-04-11
# 4   Store A  32 2024-03-14 2024-04-11
# 5   Store A  32 2024-03-14 2024-04-11
# 6   Store A  32 2024-03-14 2024-04-11
# 7   Store A  35 2024-03-15 2024-04-13
# 8   Store A  35 2024-03-15 2024-04-13
# 9   Store A  35 2024-03-15 2024-04-13
# 10  Store A  35 2024-03-15 2024-04-13
# 11  Store A  35 2024-04-14 2024-05-11
# 12  Store A  35 2024-04-14 2024-05-11
# 13  Store A  35 2024-04-14 2024-05-11
# 14  Store B  66 2024-02-15 2024-03-13
# 15  Store B  66 2024-02-15 2024-03-13
# 16  Store B  66 2024-02-15 2024-03-13
# 17  Store B  66 2024-02-15 2024-03-13
# 18  Store B  66 2024-03-14 2024-04-11
# 19  Store B  66 2024-03-14 2024-04-11

